# Target="_blank" vs window.open

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm working on an application where users enter some input and they shouldn't leave the page when clicking on share links, e.g. a Facebook share link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F">Share on Facebook</a>
```

I know it's very common to use popup windows for such links. But does it have any advantage over a simple `target="_blank"` attribute? How do you compare the two methods and which is the right practice in such cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends what HTML version you use and if you care about W3C validation. In HTML5 you can use `target="_blank"` but with previous XHTML versions you couldn't and you had to use JavaScript to achieve the same result and make your site W3C valid. I think that's the only reason why many people used this method.

Of course using Javascript makes that user has to have JavaScript enabled to open this link in new window (and using adblocks/ghostery and similar addons make block some JavaScript) so I think if you only can, you should use `target="_blank"`

Comment: "_It depends what HTML version you use and if you care about W3C validation._" I'm using HTML5.

Comment: So I would definitely go for `target="_blank"` in your case

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm under the impression that there is NO compelling reason to use XHTML over html5....

Comment: There isn't in almost all cases at the moment. I meant XHTML 1.0 when HTML5 haven't existed yet.

Comment: @ZachLysobey There are plenty of reasons to use XHTML5: Because XHTML is always valid XML it means that documents can be easily handled by systems that operate on well-formatted structured XML (such as the `xml` type in SQL) or by XML-handling libraries (like `System.Xml`) which otherwise are impossible to do as HTML5 does not require well-formedness (e.g. self-closing `input` and `br` elements, or closing `li` tags, etc).  [XHTML is part of the HTML _Living Standard_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#the-xhtml-syntax) because it's essential for processing HTML as XML.

Answer (score 6):

Window.open requires Javascript and can be blocked by popup stoppers. However, it does have additional options (width, height, options, etc). On mobile browsers, many options will be ignored.

It is preferred to use _blank as it is native to HTML whenever possible.

Comment: @ZachL: Thanks for the reference! I've alreay read it, though and it doesn't say anything about popup windows -- just when to use / not to use `taget="_blank"`.

Comment: That article is in reference to whether or not to ever popup a new window, not the method in which to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `target="_blank"` if you want it to work with people who have popup blocks and JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

An unusual situation in which you'd have to use `window.open` is when you want to create a document from scratch, using only JavaScript, when there's no link suited for the task. For example, you might use this when writing a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript), to build a new page (when you don't have a server to serve pages to clients). An `<a>` just wouldn't work for such a task.

Comment: Why not use an iframe in that case?

Comment: It has a different role, right? An iframe can embed something onto an already-existing page if for some reason you don't want to put it on the top level of that page, but an iframe can't be used to create an entirely new window. `window.open` lets you start out with a blank full-size (if desired) window that can be populated entirely from a different page's JS.

Comment: Then I think I don't understand your answer. If you want a clean JS context (as I understood your answer),  then an iframe is preferable since you don't need an user gesture. If you mean opening a new Tab to a dynamic document indeed an iframe wouldn't do, but a blob: url should do fine in an `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

One frequent use of `window.open()`, before [WebID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Credential_Management_API) gets wider adoption, is for OAuth authentication.

To not break the flow of the current page, this authentication is generally done on a different page, and since authentication providers generally don't allow their page to be embedded in an iframe, and that using an anchor `<a>` wouldn't allow both pages to communicate, we need to use `const popup = window.open(url)` and wait for the authentication to resolve in that popup before passing it the required info e.g through [`opener.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).